# How do you “chomp” a string in Vim?

Tags: vimscript

Suppose you run the following piece of vimscript:

```
let @z = system("date")
```

This will put a string version of the current date into the z register, but the string will end with a newline that I don’t want. Is there a built-in way (similar to Perl’s [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)) to get rid of a string’s trailing newlines?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `substitute()`, or define a function:

```
function! Chomp(string)
    return substitute(a:string, '\n\+$', '', '')
endfunction
```

This variant will call `system` for you and then chomp the result:

```
function! ChompedSystem( ... )
    return substitute(call('system', a:000), '\n\+$', '', '')
endfunction
```

(This function is also available in my [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433) as `ingo#system#Chomped`.)

Comment: This works, but why the weird `call` syntax? Why not just give `Chomp` a parameter called `string` and then pass `a:string` to `substitute`?

Comment: @bdesham Because `Chomp()` is passing whatever arguments it gets on to `system()`, stripping the trailing newline from its output, and returning that.

Comment: Right. `system()` has an optional `{input}` argument, and this handles any of these generically. If you don't need this, just do it the conventional way.

Comment: that looks awfully like regex, is it possible to chomp all digits as well?

Comment: @Fuseteam: I'm not sure what you exactly have in mind, but if you replace `\n\+$` with `\d*\n\+$`, any trailing digits will be removed as well. However, I probably would not combine that very application-specific cutting with the generic removal of the trailing newline, and rather do a second `substitute(l:result, '\d*$', '', '')` after receiving the chomped `l:result`, to have cleaner code.

Comment: ah thanks for the tip my goal is more to just strip all digits rather than removing trailing newlines, substitute seemed perfect for that so i commented on this answer hehe, thanks again

Answer (score 28):

```
let @z = systemlist('date')[0]
```

removes the newline for you.

Comment: I think this is probably the approach I’ll actually use, but I accepted the other answer because it’s more generally applicable. (For example, it will remove trailing newlines from a multiline string while leaving other newlines alone.)

Comment: Note that this won't work correctly for systems which use something other than `\n` for newline.  `systemlist()` only removes the `\n`, not any `\r`.

Comment: Note that this will cause an error if the called function doesn't produce any output. To avoid this and get an empty string instead: `get(systemlist("date"), 0, "")`

Answer (score 14):

Vim [v8.0.1630](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/295ac5ab5e840af6051bed5ec9d9acc3c73445de) added a `trim()` function that removes characters (by default whitespace) from the end or beginning (both by default) of strings:

```
let @z = trim(system("date"))
```

For more details see [`:help trim()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#trim%28%29).

Answer (score 6):

Christian Brabandt has listed [a number of different methods](https://superuser.com/a/935646/52910) over on superuser.com.

I like this one because it is short:

```
let @z = system("date")[:-2]
```

Comment: I wonder how it handles `\r\n` type of line endings...

Comment: @x-yuri That is certainly worth checking Don't quote me on this, but I _think_ Vim-on-Windows will normalise those line-endings to `\n` before returning them.

Comment: Yes, with `system()` newlines in return values are normalized to LF (e.g. from Win32 CRLF).

Answer (score 0):

```
let output = split(system("ls"), "\n")
```

This will give you an array of the stout without newlines at the end.