# Quickly calculate the total of a column of numbers

Tags: visual-mode, arithmetic

I'm writing down a markdown table which looks like this:

```
| 13/05/15 | 09:30-16:00 |  6.5 |
| 14/05/15 | 10:00-16:30 |  6.5 |
| 16/05/15 | 15:30-01:00 |  9.5 |
| 21/05/15 | 09:00-16:30 |  7.5 |
| 22/05/15 | 08:30-17:00 |  8.5 |
| 28/05/15 | 09:30-15:30 |  6   |
| 02/06/15 | 09:00-20:00 | 11   |
| 03/06/15 | 08:30-22:30 | 14   |
```

I'm looking for a way to quickly calculate the total of the third column and insert it in the buffer. The solution I have in mind would make use of visual-block mode (to select all the numbers) and maybe of the expression register (to do the math).

Would this be possible using native Vim commands? If not, is there a plugin that can help me?

Comment: You can have a look at this article : http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_vim_as_calculator

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I wrote a plugin: https://github.com/sk1418/HowMuch  which supports visual selection and does math calculations.

By default the plugin supports three math-expression evaluation engines: Gnu bc, python, and vimscript. You can do the calculations on a certain one or let the plugin automatically choose one for you.

It works with your example like this:

[image]

For details please read the README on github.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd include the keystrokes required to select, sum and insert in your answer.

Comment: @pdoherty926 `For details please read the README on github.` Even if I put the keystrokes I pressed for this problem here, I don't see how helpful it could be, it is just 3 or 4 key-combinations. If my script is really needed by someone, he/she will check the details anyway.

Answer (score 24):

If you don't want to use plugins or drop to a bash script, you can do something like the following:

- `c-V {motions} "ay` copy column into `"a`
- `:let @a = substitute(@a, 'c-V c-J', '+', 'g')` replace the column newlines with `+`
- `ic-R=c-Ra` run the replaced `"a` through the expression register

Alternatively: make the expression history entry re-usable for further sums of columns

- `ctrl-V {motions} y` put column into yank register `""`
- `ictrl-R=eval(substitute(@", '\n', '+', 'g'))`

Repeating for another column:

- `ctrl-V {motion} y` (unchanged)
- `ictrl-R=<CR>` or if you did something else with the expression register, cycle through the history with the up arrow key (or with `ctrl-P` if you remapped it):
  `ictrl-R=<up>...<up><CR>`

Comment: For some reason I only managed to use your solution with double quotes `"` instead single quotes `'` on the `substitute` command. Do you know if is there any reason for that ?

Comment: @vappolinario it works both ways for me, so I'm afraid I don't know, sorry.

Comment: @Hovercouch Could you elaborate on the third step? How, exactly, would one go about running the replacement through the expression register?

Comment: How about making a map: `    nnoremap <c-s> :s/$/\=eval(substitute(@0, '[^0-9]', '+', 'g'))/<cr>`

Comment: @SergioAraujo I had to do this to clean it up a bit and avoid leading and trailing or duplicate + characters in messy columns: nnoremap <expr> <c-s> 'i' . eval(trim(substitute(@", '[^0-9][^0-9]*', '+', 'g'), '+')) . '<Esc>'

Comment: This looks interesting because it's got potential to be just a line in the `vimrc` and a nice light weight solution to a common problem. It doesn't work for me though, although I'm pretty sure I'm executing it incorrectly. As @pdoherty926 also asks, it could use more description of how to actually execute. What does `ictrl-R=<CR>` mean? Do you type `i` in normal mode and then hit the CTRL-R combination, and then start typing again? Does `<CR>` mean type `<CR>` or does it mean hit return? I tried a few and managed to crash gvim on linux! I don't think that has ever happened to me before.

Comment: @NeilG it means "type ctrl-R in insert-mode", odd that it's breaking for you. `<CR>` means "hit return".

Comment: Don't forget `gv` to reselect the last visual region for quicker resumming.

Answer (score 21):

```
:r!awk '{sum+=$6} END {print "Total: "sum}' %
```

Explanation:

```
:r ........... read (put result in this file)
! ............ external command
awk .......... external tool
{sum+=$6} .... sixth field (awk considers spaces as field separator)
END .......... at the end
{print "Total: "sum} --> string "Total: " plus your result
% ............ current file
```

Here's a function that uses Vim's [expression register](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#quote=) instead of `awk`:

```
" This function requires you to select the numbers
fun! SumVis()
    try
        let l:a_save = @a
        norm! gv"ay
        let @a = substitute(@a,'[^0-9. ]','+','g')
        exec "norm! '>o"
        exec "norm! iTotal \<c-r>=\<c-r>a\<cr>"
     finally
        let @a = l:a_save
     endtry
endfun
vnoremap <leader>s :<C-u>call SumVis()<cr>
```

Using the mapping above, all you have to do after loading the function is select the numbers you want to sum and use `<leader>s` to sum up the selected area.

**Function explanation:**

It uses `try/finally/endtry` structure to capture errors.

```
let l:a_save = @a ............................. if we have register 'a' we save it temporarily
norm! gv"ay ................................... gv --> reselects and captures selection to 'register a'
let @a = substitute(@a,'[^0-9. ]','+','g') .... removes all but numbers, dots and spaces from 'register a' and puts '+' among the numbers
exec "norm! '>o"  ............................. opens new line below selection. see :h '>
exec "norm! iTotal: \<c-r>=\<c-r>a\<cr>" ...... insert "Total: " plus 'expression register result
let @a = l:a_save ............................. restores original 'a' register content
```

If you want to try this function, do the following:
Copy this function in your browser and run this command on vim `:@+`
this will allow you to use `:call SumVis()` normally.

```
:@+ ......... loads `+` register making the function available
```

It needs you to make a visual block selection with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, unselect and finally call the function. Or you can use the suggested map which by itself removes the selection before calculating.

Comment: In that SumVis() function you could add a `let @a = substitute(@a, '^[\n\t ]\+\|[\n\t ]\+$', '', 'g')` before the existing substitution to remove beginning and trailing whitespace, and add a `\+` to the substitution to allow for multiple whitespaces in between the numbers.

Comment: Vim has now a [`trim`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2867/how-do-you-chomp-a-string-in-vim#26557) function, meaning you can do: `let @a = substitute(trim(@a),'[^0-9. ]','+','g')`

Answer (score 8):

My [csv plugin](https://github.com/chrisbra/csv.vim) allows this. Use the `:SumCol` command and be sure to read the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Making a plugin or coding this in vimscript seems a little heavy. I believe in a plugin-free vim, and good composition with external tools.

Here is a 1-time command, based on user2571881's, that works even if the buffer has not been saved.

```
:%!awk -F '|' '{print; sum+=$4}; END {print "Total: "sum}'
```

If you want to save this command for future use, you might want to name it:

```
:command! -range=% -nargs=1 SumColumn <line1>,<line2>!awk -F '|' '{print; sum+=$('<args>' + 1)} END {print "Total: "sum}'
```

It works with visual selection. If you select a few rows and go into command mode, vim will prefix your command with `:'<,'>`, which is the line range for the visual selection. So you can run:

```
:'<,'>SumColumn 3
```

and it will only sum the 3rd column of the selected rows. By default the range is `%`, so

```
:SumColumn 3
```

will sum the 3rd column of all lines.

EDIT: If you want to be able to specify other field separators and default the column counted to the last one, you can cover the command in `bash` and handle the arguments with it, like this:

```
:command! -range=% -nargs=* SumColumn <line1>,<line2>!bash -c 'awk -F ${2:-|} "{print; sum+=\$(${1:-NF - 2} + 1)} END {print \"Total: \"sum}"' sumcolumn <args>
```

Now,

```
:SumColumn
```

will count the last column of a table with "|" field separators,

```
:SumColumn 3
```

will count the 3rd column of a table with "|" field separators, and

```
:SumColumn 3 +
```

will count the 3rd column of a table with "+" field separators.

Comment: How can one deal with other possible field separators? Just for making the solution more generic.

Comment: @user2571881, I've edited the answer, showing that.

Comment: @JoL adding functions like `SumColumn` to vimrc means you simply have your 'plugins' in your vimrc. Hopefully, you are good at maintaining this with time. For me plugins provide documentation, separation into meaningful parts, taking advantage of others ingenuity. I contribute to upstream which improves amazing plugins which no one has time to create all of them on their own (except tpope). Do you not use vim-surround, vim-fugitive, vim-easy-align/vim-lion, vim-unimpaired,  vim-commentary, ultisnips or ft-specific ones such as vim-go, vim-rails, vimtex?

Comment: @Hotschke When I got here, I saw the question and thought, "well, just pipe through awk." But then, I saw the accepted answer was, "hey, download this hundreds of LOC plugin and install it." Third answer was, "hey, download this thousands of LOC plugin and install it." It's overkill and bloat. Even if you needed to sum columns more than once in your life, it's overkill. My answer is meant to show how you can do this in a single no-plugins, no-nonsense command if you only need to do this once, and how you can make a simple command with parameters out of it if you need to do this often.

Comment: @Hotschke To answer your question, I used to install every plugin under the sun that looked remotely cool, but then my vim was incredibly slow (read "a little laggy" which is intolerable for an editor). On looking more into vim docs, I realized that I didn't really need the plugins. Many of the stock features were good enough, and, for those that vim didn't have, the shell was the way to go. Foundationally (ignoring exceptions it's made), as per the Unix philosophy, vim is an editor that interoperates well with other OS tooling. I believe that's the way to best utilize it. No plugins since.

Comment: @JoL Thanks for your thoughts. I certainly understand you. I also care about startuptime, ditched quite a few plugins and have become quite picky about added startup time from plugins. However, for certain tasks I really enjoy, e.g. an operator for commenting, an indent-text object, surround operator, snippets for some languages which have a lot of boilerplate code, being able to look immediately at the git history of a file when editing. I have also plugins such SimpylFold for folding in python files which complete incomplete vim features. I guess I will always use plugins.

Answer (score 5):

If the columns are properly aligned, this can be done with a simple oneliner.

1. first select the column in [block-wise visual mode](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/visual.txt.html#visual%2dblock) as other answers have demonstrate -> `CTRL-V` + move the cursor
2. yank the selection with `y`
3. type: `:echo eval(join(split(@", '\_s\+'), '+'))` which splits the text yanked on spaces and new lines, rejoin the element with `+` character, and evaluate the string.
4. another way to proceed: replace newlines with `+` and evaluate: `:echo eval(substitute(@", "\n", '+', 'g'))` -- `eval()` is the closest thing to `reduce` we have.

If not, you'll have to use other tricks to count fields. For instance, `split(getline('.'), "[ \t|]\\+")` can be used to split the columns from a row in your array. From there, it becomes as simple as:

1. select your lines in visual mode
2. `:echo eval(join(map(getline("'<", "'>"), { -> split(v:val, "[ \t|]\\+")[2] }), '+'))`

In order to get rid of the magical values (field number - 1, and `+`), it can become a command

```
:command! -range=% -nargs=+ OnField 
    \ echo { field, what -> eval(join(map(getline(<line1>, <line2>), { -> split(v:val, "[ \t|]\\+")[field-1] }), what))}(<f-args>)
```

Which can be used with:

```
:OnField  3 +
:2,5OnField  3 +
:'<,'>Onfield 3 *   " after line-wise selection
....
```

Note: Here I use lambdas from Vim 7.4.1xxx

Comment: As of [8.2.0878](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.0878), Vim provides a `reduce()` function.  So you could also write: `echo split(@", '\_s\+')->map("str2float(v:val)")->reduce({a,v -> a+v})`.

Comment: What is `'\_s\+'` in step 3? It looks like a very strange regex.

Comment: @BigMcLargeHuge, it should be documented under `:h /\_s` and `:h /\+`. It means any kind of spaces (even newlines), and at least one, in default mode (see documentation about magic mode)

Answer (score 1):

#### vmap `++` from plugin `vmath` by Damian Conway

1. Install plugin from [github](https://github.com/thoughtstream/Damian-Conway-s-Vim-Setup/blob/master/plugin/vmath.vim) (only 178 sloc)
   e.g.

   ```
   $ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thoughtstream/Damian-Conway-s-Vim-Setup/master/plugin/vmath.vim -P ~/.vim/pack/manual/start/damians-tools/plugin
   ```
2. Add mapping to your vimrc

   ```
   vmap <silent><expr>  ++  VMATH_YankAndAnalyse()
   ```

   However, I would suggest to use something else, e.g. `gA`
3. Move to the third colum `2f|` and select the column in visual-block mode `<C-V>G$`
4. Press `++` (or your chosen mapping)
5. Results are shown and stored in registers (sum in `s`)
6. Insert sum from register `s`, e.g. with `"sp`

For a presentation of this plugin see the YouTube video [Damian Conway, "More Instantly Better Vim" - OSCON 2013](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHm36-na4-4#t=29m00s) (starting at minute 29).

Answer (score 1):

### External cli tool [`csvstat`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.3/scripts/csvstat.html) from [csvkit](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit)

```
:!csvstat -d '|' -H -c 4 --sum %
69.5
```

Short explanation of the options

- `-d DELIMITER` Delimiting character of the input CSV file. Here `|`.
- `-H` Specify that the input CSV file has no header row.
- `-c COLUMNS` A comma separated list of column indices or names to
     be examined. Defaults to all columns.
- `--sum` Only output sums.

This tool also provides min, max, mean, median, stdev (standard deviation), count unique values, list of frequent values.

Insert into file with

```
<C-r>=system("csvstat -d '|' -H -c 4 --sum FILENAME 2> /dev/null")
```

#### Installation

On macOS *csvkit* is available via homebrew and on Debian/Ubuntu and similar it can be installed with `$ sudo apt install csvkit`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to do it: First, add the following to your .vimrc:

```
command! -range Add
    \ silent exec "norm gv\"ay" |
    \ let array = split(@a, "[\\n\\t ]\\+") |
    \ let sum = 0.00 |
    \ for item in array |
    \     let sum += str2float(item) |
    \ endfor |
    \ echo sum
```

then reload vim, and highlight a column of numbers in visual selection mode, and then type:

```
:'<,'>Add
```

and it will print out the sum of the numbers in the column.

Answer (score 1):

I just did it this way:

- thru the block selection copied all values, as a column to a new buffer
- quickly edited the text to construct a mathematical expression
  [image]
- copy/pasted it to the default system calculator
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

`ctrl-v` for block select,
select the column,
paste below `G` `p`

select the pasted text,
press `I`, now you are in insert mode, type `+`
press `esc esc` to escape. now each line has a +
select it again
press `J`

select the line with `V`
type command `:!bc`, it will show as `:'<,'>!bc`

you got the sum

[image: demo]

Comment: `V!bc` is the same as `!!bc`. for the join, you could either use `gvJ` or `:'>j[oin]`

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know about '!!bc`