# Why does system(cmd) append ^@ to its output?

Tags: vimscript, neovim

I want to set node's executable path for neovim. So I have added this line in `init.vim`.

```
let g:coc_node_path = system('which node')
```

But when I open nvim I get this error.

```
[coc.nvim] "/home/akash/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.0/bin/node^@" is not executable, checkout https://nodejs.org/en/download
```

But if I edit the path manually,

```
let g:coc_node_path = '/home/akash/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.0/bin/node'
```

then it works fine. So why does `system('which node')` append `^@` to its output?

Comment: See also: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2867/18609

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What a coincidence. I encountered this exact same thing a few hours before you posted this. I just figured it was a line-ending issue and solved it by wrapping the `system()` call in a call to [`trim()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#trim()).

Since you mentioned it I since verified that the cause is the presence of a newline in the output of `system()`.

So you can solve this with a `trim()` call that directly addresses the problem like so...

```
trim(system(...), "\n")
```

If you are using an older version of Vim which doesn't have `trim()` you can use something like this instead...

```
let foo = system(...)
let foo = strcharpart(foo, 0, strchars(foo)-1))
```

Or this...

```
let foo = substitute(system(...), "\n$", "", "")
```

**Update:** I should point out that this isn't a bug or anything. When running a command from the shell you'll get a newline at the end and that's expected. `system()` does the right thing and passes everything back to the caller. It just so happens that there's a fairly common use case, assigning the result to a variable, where we don't want that newline.

(Note: One thing that might not be expected is that Vim normalizes line-endings on non-unix systems so, for example, Windows CRLF becomes LF. It makes sense but one needs to be aware of it.)

Comment: As some recent answers pointed out, `trim()` was only introduced in Vim [v8.0.1630](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/295ac5ab5e840af6051bed5ec9d9acc3c73445de), so it might not be available if you're using stock Vim shipped with a somewhat older distribution.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Thx for the reminder.

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is the newline at the end of the command, as [@BLayer's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/28634/18609) states.

A better approach for this specific case of finding a binary would be to use the Vimscript function [`exepath()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#exepath%28%29) here instead of shelling out to the `which` command:

```
let g:coc_node_path = exepath('node')
```

This is more efficient (since it doesn't need to spawn an external process) and ends up avoiding the issue with the newline altogether.